# Why my jupiters that I bought on whalet market have disapered from my phantom wallet?

Tags: solana-program, wallet, phantom, phantom-wallet, jupiter

I had 360.75 jup on my wallet and now I have 0 but all the other coins are fine, does anyone knows what happened ?

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to ask this question. Perhaps the Phantom wallet discord might be a better place to ask this. Saying that, could it be that your wallet got hacked? It's impossible to help you without more info. At the very least you'd need to share your wallet address so people can help you look into it.

Answer (score 0):

For assistance with this, please contact Phantom support via Settings in your Phantom wallet.